# Adding 1 hr dynamically in android

Tags: java, android

I have a code

```
String date = 05/09/13 10.55 PM;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm a");
Date testDate = null;

testDate = sdf.parse(date);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println(".....Date..." + newFormat);
```

And this **gives me output as**

```
 05/09/13 10:55:00 PM
```

**What i actually need:**

```
05/09/13 11:55:00 PM //i want to add an hour to the date I got
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code This will add 1 hour and print required result.

```
String date = "05/09/13 10.55 PM";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm a");
        Date testDate = null;

        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
            // Add 1 hour logic
            Calendar tmpCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
            tmpCalendar.setTime(testDate); 
            tmpCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);           
            testDate = tmpCalendar.getTime();           

            // Continue with your logic
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
            System.out.println(".....Date..." + newFormat);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output**

```
.....Date...05/09/2013 11:55:00 PM
```

Comment: @Tarsem Thank you.. you made my points out of 10K thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(testDate, 1);

[DateUtils.addHours](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#addHours%28java.util.Date,%20int%29)

**Edit:**

Here u are:

```
String date = 05/09/13 10.55 PM;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm a");
Date testDate = sdf.parse(date);

Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(testDate, 1);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String newFormat = formatter.format(newDate);
System.out.println(".....Date..." + newFormat);
```